# openssl "no shared cipher" for ECDSA cert (RSA works fine)

Tags: openssl, certificate, ecdsa

When I try to test my ecdsa cert using openssl it says "no cipher suite found".  However, RSA works fine and I have actually used use another ECDSA certificate in my production test (AWS IoT) and it works fine.  I can't figure out why openssl isn't happy???  I have the terminal output from my two sessions including my certificate and key pem output (one client and one server running on the same PC).  Any ideas what could be wrong???

/////// Server terminal /////////////////////////

```
$ openssl.exe version
OpenSSL 1.0.2o  27 Mar 2018

$  openssl.exe s_server -key test.key -cert test.crt -verify 0 -accept 443 -WWW verify depth is 0
Using default temp DH parameters
ACCEPT
4294956672:error:1408A0C1:SSL routines:ssl3_get_client_hello:no shared cipher:s3_srvr.c:1427:
ACCEPT

/////// Same system in a second terminal ////////

$ openssl s_client -connect 127.0.0.1:443 -CAfile test.crt
CONNECTED(00000003)
4294956672:error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure:s23_clnt.c:802:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 7 bytes and written 308 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : 0000
    Session-ID:
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key:
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1531517108
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---


$ cat test.crt
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----

$ cat test.key
-----BEGIN EC PARAMETERS-----
BggqhkjOPQMBBw==
-----END EC PARAMETERS-----
-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----
MHcCAQEEIMtuI/yMncCnlYB/7ev8NaUWR0WYeeuIX35QVjHtA2vaoAoGCCqGSM49
AwEHoUQDQgAEVZMDBw3mvpNAQ5OhEOMRLaEqih/K//AYWfypfBAh5E5GfYuKeq5Q
wfvvS+3ZJ6OUlH3efJX9eZBW7doJXGMy8w==
-----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Comment: If these are throw away practice certificate and key, include test.key so that we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: Added test.key to original post.  thanks.

Comment: Your cert has KeyUsage `certSign,crlSign` which is not usable for any ciphersuite, accordingly the only ciphersuites `s_server` would accept are anonymous aka unauthenticated ones which are disabled by default and you did not enable (and you _should_ not enable because in most situations they're insecure). Add (at least) digSign, or drop the extension altogether (which allows all usages). The same rule _should_ apply to RSA but for hysterical raisins OpenSSL does not consistently enforce it.

Comment: Oh, great catch, thanks.  Updated to "keyUsage = keyCertSign, cRLSign, digitalSignature" and it works.  In AWS I was chaining to another cert but I thought I would do a simpler "test" to try out the openssl s_server...